# For statement print

Tags: java

I want to write code that reversely outputs numbers whose range I entered.

First I input `11`, second `5`. My program then however printed `5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11` instead of the reversed output `11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5`.

Is there anything I did wrong in the *for-statement*? Would appreciate your help.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the first number");
int min = reader.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter a second number");
int max = reader.nextInt();

for (int i = max; i < min + 1; i++)
{
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Update the question with the error

Comment: You haven't told us what error you get. And nothing in your code prints anything about the relative sizes of the numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of infomation , After input the number 11 as first , 5 as second , the line printed is 5,6,7,8,9,10,11 still , Instead of the reverse way of 11,10,9,8,7,6,5 , Anything that i've do wrong in the for sentence? @bmargulies

Comment: Thanks for giving us more info, can you please include them in your original answer by **editing** it instead of posting a comment? Thanks :)

Comment: These kind of issues are generally easily solved by debugging the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

That is relatively easy. Let's closely analyse your code then you will immediately see the "*why*".

First you enter a **11**, it gets saved inside `min`. After that you enter **5** which gets saved inside `max`.

Now you iterate and you start at `max` and from their increase up to `min`. When we now put in the values we iterate from **5** (`max`) to **11** (`min`).

You need to reverse that and correctly enter **5** to `min` and **11** to `max`. And after that decrease your counter instead of increasing it with `i--` instead of `i++`. The same holds for your **stop criterion**, it needs to be reversed as you want it to iterate as long as your counter is **above** your `min` value.

So the loop then looks like:

```
for (int i = max; i >= min; i--)
{
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: I think i have understand , Sorry for asking such a small mistake , And thank you for your correction on my mistake

Comment: You're welcome. There was a time for all of us where we did those small mistakes too. Just learn from it and next time try to debug it on your own, its not that hard. Always try to go through it step by step, add some debug prints here and there just to see which variable has what content at which step :)

Answer (score 0):

To print numbers in descending

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter the first number");
int first = reader.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter a second number");
int second = reader.nextInt();

int min=Math.min(first,second);
int max=Math.max(first,second);
for (int i = max; i > min; i--)
{
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

with this you don't need to restrict user to enter first number as min or second number as max whatever you enter you will get response in descending order

Answer (score 0):

Decrement from `i` instead of increment:

```
for (int i = max; i >= min; i--) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```